# JSON and PHP Decoded Arrays and Object not pulling multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, loops

So I have this API, I'm trying to pull multiple values from the keys provided.
I can't seem to get more than two images even when my call meets the if requirements.

This is an example of what my API gets when I call it. in JSON format.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "ProData",
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": "2000002",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": false,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url":"https://example.randomcharactercloudhostedimage.JPG",
                            "height": "4.00",
                            "width": "200.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2000003",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": false,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://example.randomcharactercloudhostedimage.JPG",
                            "height": "1.00",
                            "width": "100.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2000004",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Mounted",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url":"https://example.randomcharactercloudhostedimage.JPG",
                            "height": "3.00",
                            "width": "300.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2000005",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Mounted",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url":"https://example.randomcharactercloudhostedimage.JPG",
                            "height": "800.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2000006",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Mounted",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url":"https://example.randomcharactercloudhostedimage.JPG",
                            "height": "800.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

I was struggling getting my code to work in the first place. I'm a self taught programmer working in WordPress. I've been through the whole MDN PHP site like a hundred times now, and applying what I see is more difficult than I initially anticipated.

Here's where I got... I didn't include some of the initial assignments as I built them into functions I use earlier on, that aren't as relevant. And I know my issue is only related to these Loops. Using "foreach" did make a ton of headway. But here I am stuck so any help would be awesome.

```
foreach ($value->files as $dimensionvalue) {
        $prodimgid = $dimensionvalue->id;
        if ($dimensionvalue->media_content == 'Photo - Primary') {

            foreach ($dimensionvalue->links as $dimensionlinksprim) {
                $prodimageprim = $dimensionlinksprim->url;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($value->files as $dimensionvalue) {
        $prodimgmntid = $dimensionvalue->id;
        if ($dimensionvalue->media_content == 'Photo - Mounted') {
            if ($prodimgid !== $prodimgmntid) {
                foreach ($dimensionvalue->links as $dimensionlinksmnt) {

                    $prodimagesmnt = $dimensionlinksmnt->url;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($dimensionvalue->id as $prodimgmntid2) {
        if ($dimensionvalue->media_content == 'Photo - Mounted') {
            if ($prodimgmntid !== $prodimgmntid2) {
                foreach ($dimensionvalue->links as $dimensionlinksmnt2) {

                    $prodimagesmnt2 = $dimensionlinksmnt2->url;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<tr class='proddatarows'><td class='rownum'>" . $i++ . "</td><td class='prodid'>" . $value->id . "</td>" . "<td>" . "<img class='prodimg' src='" . $prodimageprim . "' alt='' width='50' height='50' />" . "</td>" . "<td>" . "<img class='prodimgmnt' src='" . $prodimagesmnt . "' alt='' width='50' height='50' />" . "</td>" . "<td>" . "<img class='prodimgmnt2' src='" . $prodimagesmnt2 . "' alt='' width='50' height='50' />" . "</td>" . "</tr>";
```

I am using multiple technologies in this. Ajax, JQuery, JavaScript, WordPress, and plain old PHP. So if you have recommendations in which I could utilize any of those, I am open to anything. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I should mention, if it's helpful. I am trying to get multiple mounted images..

Comment: Why are you looping over the same thing twice to begin with?

Comment: You are overwriting `$prodimageprim` and `$prodimagesmnt` every time in those loops - so of course only the last value "survives" that in each case. You either need to create your output inside those loops, or put the values into an array/arrays, so that you can loop over that/those later on.